# Sortable rows only when a specific column is dragged

Tags: jquery

How can I sort a row when a select a specific column of a table?

```
[...]
<tbody id="table_body">
    <tr>
        <td>A</td>
        <td>10</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>B</td>
        <td>8</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>T</td>
        <td>12C</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
[...]
```

The script:

```
var fixHelper = function (e, ui) {
    ui.children().each(function () {
        $(this).width($(this).width());
    });

    return ui;
};

$(function () {
    $("#table_body").sortable({
        helper: fixHelper
    }).disableSelection();
});
```

So, I want that the rows be sorted only when I select the first column. If I select the second column, nothing happens. Is it possible?

EDIT:

I try what Pow says:

```
$('#table_body td').mousedown(function (event) {
    if ($(this).attr("class") != "add_story") {
        event.stopImmediatePropagation();
    }
});
```

But when I move one row by the column with class "add_story", every row is moved by any column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to do this by adding classes to the cells.

Then in the cells you do not want to allow dragging in, override the `mousedown` event

Markup like this:

```
<td class='grab'>A</td>
<td class='show'>10</td>
```

And script like this:

```
$(function () {
    $("tbody").sortable({
        helper: fixHelper,
        axis: "y"
    }).disableSelection();
    $('#Table_Body').not('.add_Story').mousedown(function(event){
        event.stopImmediatePropagation();
    });
});
```

[example](http://jsfiddle.net/XEMhW/)

The axis y is not necessary, I just figured it would be nice.

Comment: Pow, we have a problem. I forgot that I have dynamic class in second column. So, in each row of the second td has a class "something_1", "something_2" and so on ...

Comment: not a problem, just either use a partial attribute selector, or add the other class you are going to use after a space: `something_1 show`, `something_2 show` etc.

Comment: I will put in the question, what I put, and what is happens.

Answer (score 10):

You can also use the handle option: http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#option-handle

Give your first columns a class like "sortHandle", then in your script you can set the handle option to only sort when that column is clicked.

```
var fixHelper = function (e, ui) {
    ui.children().each(function () {
        $(this).width($(this).width());
    });

    return ui;
};

$(function () {
    $("#table_body").sortable({
        helper: fixHelper,
        handle: '.sortHandle',
    }).disableSelection();
});
```

HTML:

```
   <tbody id="table_body">
        <tr>
            <td class="sortHandle">A</td>
            <td>10</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="sortHandle">B</td>
            <td>8</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="sortHandle">T</td>
            <td>12C</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
```

Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/uWZ59/2/